# Using service builder generated classes in other modules

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder, liferay-7.1

I'm using Liferay 7.1 GA1 Version. I have generated my service/api java classes with service-builder that Liferay IDE provides me.

How can I use these service classes in my other modules? I would like to use "MyServiceBuilder" generated classes in "MyPortlet" like you can see in the following picture.

Thanks.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOs4h.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure your project like this:

[image: structure]

in the gradle file of the portlet add:
*compileOnly project(":modules:test-service:test-service-api")*

Right click and select Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project on the test-service folder.

Then use OSGi Declarative Services in your portlet:
*@Reference

protected FooLocalService _fooLocalService;*